# Can you configure Android Room to generate Kotlin code and not Java

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Im currently investigating Android Room.

As google have announced Kotlin is their preferred language for Android development I was puzzled to see Room generates Java code.

Is there any way to configure Room to generate Kotlin code?

Comment: Based on my experience using Room, and the documentation, I'm almost certain there is no configuration option for generation of Kotlin `_Impl` files.  Does that concern you?  You can still write your app code in Kotlin, even though the generated Room implementation is Java.

Comment: The only concern I have is associated with Unit Testing & Mocking. As the generated code is Java being called by Kotlin code I am unable to Spy on the generated DAO's when the generated functions are suspend functions.

Answer (score 1):

Room [2.6.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.6.0-alpha01) added support for Kotlin CodeGen and I would guess the aim is to release as part of the version 2.6.0. There are additional restrictions to your DAO noted in the release notes.